# Multilined and Misformatted Table of Contents in Master/Subfiles Document

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, subfiles

I'm trying to figure out what I did that screwed up the formatting of this course notes template.  I apologize for not having a better MWE, but it seems to all have parts together to it.

MWE (edited): 
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}

```
\newcommand{\classheader}[1]{\newpage\section*{#1}
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{(#1)}
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\parbox[t]{0.9in}{\centering Page \thepage\\ \classheader}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}


\section*{Introduction}

\include{SecurityisMathematics}

\end{document}
```

**Security is Mathematics.tex (as an MWE)**

```
\classheader{Security is Mathematics}
\section{Security is Mathematics}\label{security-is-mathematics}

Insert Text Here
```

These two documents, compiled while in the same directory, provide the following first page as output.  Not exactly what I'm looking for.  Any thoughts on how to fix this and make it cleaner?  Thanks all!

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drastically reduce your ca 500 line long master document to the following MWE that still reproduces your problem with the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\classheader}[1]{\newpage\section*{#1}
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{(#1)}
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\parbox[t]{0.9in}{\centering Page \thepage\\ \classheader}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}


\section*{Introduction}

\include{SecurityisMathematics}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you now comment out line 4 (`\phantomsection`...), you achieve the following output:

[image]

Applied to your original example, you get:

[image]

---

Apart from that, you might be interested in using a different documentclass like `report` or even `book` that are better suited for longer documents. They also provide the `chapter` command that automatically starts on a new page.